# What is the attenuation spectrum of radio waves in pure water?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Here is a plot of microwave attenuation in atmosphere:

[image]
([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Micrwavattrp.png))

I'm looking for a similar plot, but for pure water, and a frequency range covering at least 100 MHz to 2 GHz, hopefully more.

Comment: There is a plot from which you can extract that data in the classic E&M text by Jackson. It actually covers most of the EM spectrum, but...

Comment: A quick Google search gave this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water

Comment: @hdhondt Unfortunately the plot there ends at 30 GHz and only mentions that absorption is "continuous" from there onwards.

Comment: I came across [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01457.pdf) article in my research. It doesn't describe the relationship between Damping and the Frequency, but it does show some related correlations for pure water in the context of electromagnetic absorption.